# Replace the subsetted and modified data back into the main dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

I have a data frame with 20 rows, I randomly select `n` rows and modify them. How can I put the modified value back to the original data frame with only the modified value being different?

```
df<- data.frame(rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 1))
n = 8
a<- data.frame(df[ c(1, sample(2:(nrow(df)-1), n), nrow(df) ), ])
a$changedvalue <- a[,1]*(2.5)
```

Now I want to replace the values of the original dataframe `df` with the values of `a$changedvalue` such that only the sampled values are changed while everything else is same in `df`. I tried doing something like this but it's not working.

```
df %>% a[order(as.numeric(rownames(a))),]
```

I just want to point out that in my original dataset the data are timeseries data, so maybe they can be used for the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing `data.frame(df[ c(1, sample(2:(nrow(df)-1), n), nrow(df) ), ])`

You can define the rows you want to use, lets call it `rows`

`rows <- c(1, sample(2:(nrow(df)-1), n), nrow(df) )`

Now you can do

```
a<- data.frame(df[rows, ])
a$changedvalue <- a[,1]*(2.5)

df[rows, ] <- a$changedvalue
```

Comment: Thankyou. In my original data, I have three columns, so your method will modify the values of all three columns, not just the one column ```a[,1]``` .  Is there a way to modify just that one column?

Comment: `df[rows, 1 ] <- a$changedvalue`